# What's the best way to display a single record in a webpage?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html, master-detail

I have a master/detail form.  I have a jquery grid for the detail, works fine.  I'm not sure how to display the master single record.  I don't want to use an html table.  Just a styled list maybe?

I've was always so spoiled with asp.net controls in webforms that I don't know any good practices for this sort of thing.  I am using PHP and CodeIgniter if that matters.  Outside of tables (that was from old classic asp, when I did everything manually), I can only think of a list that wraps php tags with the proper data from my database.  I don't know that I want to use jquery for the master part.

For example, at the moment I have this in my view:

```
<?php foreach ($search_result->result() as $row):?>
    <div class="post">
        <h1 class="title">
            <?=$row->product_name?></br>
            <?=$row->product?></br>
            <?=$row->description . '/' . $row->price . ' - ' . $row->tax?>
        </h1>
        <div class="entry">     
            <?=anchor('products/getproducts/' . $row->productid, 'Products\'s Information')?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

I could wrap those in some html tags that have ID and names, so that when I press a button on them the grid grabs those values to populate my grid.

Answer (score 0):

However it is most beneficial to the user...

A styled list is simple, clean, and presents what you need as long as it works for you.